# AWS Cognito on Android - How to get a new session from a refresh token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, security, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito as mu authentication provider for an android app and I have the refresh token expiration set for 30 days on my user pool.

The access token I receive is valid for up to 1 hour so I can automatically renew the users session by calling `getCurrentUser()` on the `CognitoUserPool` if the user leaves the app and comes back in within 1 hour.

However, I want to use the cached refresh token if the user comes back a few hours later so they don't need to constantly log back in. The CognitoUserPool documentation indicates that it will only use the refresh token if it is used while the access token is still active.

Doesn't this defeat the purpose of a refresh token, or is a  refresh token meant to be used only while the access token is active?

If a refresh token can't be used to get a new session how do apps keep users logged in for day/weeks/months at a time? Do they store the password on the device?

Comment: Where do you see the part where *"it will only use the refresh token if it is used while the access token is still active"*?  That seems to conflict with
    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The reason the authentication was failing is because I was using `getSession` instead of `getSessionInBackground` and it was throwing an exception because it was running on the main thread.

Comment: However, the part of the documentation I seem to be misunderstanding is `The Mobile SDK for iOS and the Mobile SDK for Android automatically refresh your ID and access tokens if there is a valid (non-expired) refresh token present, and the ID and access tokens have a minimum remaining validity of 5 minutes. If the refresh token is expired, your app user must reauthenticate by signing in again to your user pool.` says the access token must be valid for at least 5 more minutes to be refreshed.

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I interpret this as stating that the access and tokens are *continuously* kept current while the user is active, and each time they approach expiration, the SDK starts working on this background auto-refresh before the tokens reach the point where they have less than 5 minutes of validity remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito SDK internally uses refresh token to refresh the current user session:

```
//get CognitoUser instance by passing userName or emailID

CognitoUser cognitoUser = cognitoUserPool.getUser(userName);

//simply get User Session again and in your authenticationHandler, handle userSession obtained
cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

getSessionInBackground will internally use the refresh token to generate a new session without the need of passing any password.

Comment: This is not true, `AuthenticationHandler` method, `getAuthenticationDetails`, needs a valid password in order for the tokens to be refreshed. The method you mention is can only be used with a valid userid with the accompanied valid password.